# How do you render a dropdown list from data table obtained via axios in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, dropdown

I feel like this should be simple, but I've been struggling with this and would appreciate some help.

I'm trying to generate a drowdown list from a field in a data table I fetched using Axios.  The data table loads and renders just fine, but React does not recognize the list as an array and therefore can not map the items.  Both the data table and list are generated and stored in state in the same function at the same time.

Below is my code.  Any suggestions on how to do this is much appreciated.  Thanks:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import db from './db.js' //<--I have my axios db connection in a seperate file

function App() {

  const [industryData, setIndustryData] = useState([]) //
  const [industryList, setIndustryList] = useState([]) //<--This is the list I want

  const getData= async(req, res)=>{
      const response = await db.get('/getTable/industries')
      const data =  response.data;
      console.log(data) // <--Data loads fine
      setIndustryData(data) // <--Data renders fine

      //I want to get a dropdown list from one of the fields in the data above
      let list = []
      data.forEach(row=>{
        list.push(row.industry)
      })
      console.log(list) //<--this works

      const industries = new Set(list)
      console.log(industries) //<---this works

      setIndustryList(industries) 
      console.log(industryList) //<--This is empty.
   }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])


    return (
      <div className="App">
      
        //This is the dropdown I want but it's not working
        <select>
          {industryList.map(item=>(  //<---React doesn't recognize this object
            <option key={industryList.indexOf(item)}>{item}</option>
          ))}
        </select>

  
     //But rendering the original data table works.  But I don't want to do this because I don't get unique values.  I need a set.  Also it's just cleaner to use a list than an entire data set.
         <select>
            {industryData.map(item=>( //<---This works fine
              <option key={industryData.indexOf(item)}>{item.industry}</option>
            ))}
         </select>
    </div>
  );
```

}

```
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two problems at play here. Let's first start with the root problem:

> ```
> <select>
>   {industryList.map(item=>(  //<---React doesn't recognize this object
>     <option key={industryList.indexOf(item)}>{item}</option>
>   ))}
> </select>
> ```

The reason `map()` does not work is because `industryList` is a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

> ```js
> const industries = new Set(list)
> setIndustryList(industries)
> ```

`Set` objects do not have a `map()` method. (They also do not have an `indexOf()` method.)

If you aren't using any `Set` features (apart from it removing duplicate values as part of the constructor). The easiest fix would be to convert `industries` to an array before setting it as state.

This can be done with [`Array.from(industries)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the contents into an array `[...industries]`.

```js
setIndustryList(Array.from(industries))
```

If you are using some of the set features you'll want to do this same conversion, but during rendering instead.

```
<select>
  {Array.from(industryList).map((item, index) => (
    <option key={index}>{item}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

`Array.from()` also allows us to pass a [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#mapfn) `mapFn`. This does the same as `map()` would do, but does it during the Set to Array conversion. Causing one less iteration.

```
<select>
  {Array.from(industryList, (item, index) => (
    <option key={index}>{item}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

---

Now, let's move on to the second problem that arose when you where trying to debug the above.

> ```js
> setIndustryList(industries) 
> console.log(industryList) //<--This is empty.
> ```

Why is `industryList` empty?

Let's look at the `useState` documentation for this one:

> ##### Caveats
>
> - The `set` function **only updates the state variable for the *next* render**. If you read the state variable after calling the `set` function, [you will still get the old](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value) value that was on the screen before your call.

When you log `industryList` directly after using `setIndustryList()`, it does not yet hold its new value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  Using a set instead of a list was the problem.  Looks like I will have to convert all sets to lists or use lists to begin with if I have unique items.  The second issue you pointed with the render is actually not a problem.  It's working for both the industry data and industry list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be related to the asynchronous nature of the `getData` function. When you call `setIndustryList(list)`, it may not have the updated `industryData` immediately. What you can do is, inside `getData` instead of `industryData.forEach` you can get the data from `data.foreach`. Here is the updated `getData` function you can use.

```
const getData= async(req, res)=>{
      const response = await db.get('/getTable/industries')
      const data =  response.data;
      console.log(data) // <--Data loads fine
      setIndustryData(data) // <--Data renders fine

      //I want to get a dropdown list from one of the fields in the data above
      let list = new Set()
      data.forEach(row=>{
        list.add(row.industry)
      })
      console.log(list) //<---this is empty for some reason.
      setIndustryList(list) //<--This is empty.
   }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually did try that at first but it didn't work.  I'll update the post to reflect this approach as I think it's better.